# Get Apache to route http requests to IIS

Tags: apache, http, iis, request, routes

I want to put an Apache web server in front of an IIS web server in order to route incoming http requests from Apache to IIS for processing (and send the responses back to Apache).

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We've used mod_proxy in Apache to create a reverse proxy for incoming web requests.  This allowed us to keep an old URL around that some customers were using and couldn't get away from.  It presents some challenges when posting large amounts of data, but this should do what you want.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.1/mod/mod_proxy.html